# Microsoft Access error cannot find .mdb but database is .accdb

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledbconnection

I'm doing a sample program accessing a Microsoft Access database.  It is a .accdb file.  The name of the Database is ACRONYM_DB.accdb and has one data table called ACRONYM.  My code is below :

```
string currentLoc = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString();

ObservableCollection<Acronym.Acronym> acrOC = new ObservableCollection<Acronym.Acronym>();
string ConnStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + currentLoc + "\\Assets\\ACRONYM_DB.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=password";

OleDbConnection MyConn = new OleDbConnection(ConnStr);
MyConn.Open();
OleDbCommand myCommand = MyConn.CreateCommand();
myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM ACRONYM_DB.ACRONYM WHERE ACRONYM_NAME=" + acrName;
OleDbDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

On the Execute reader line I'm gettting the error :

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467259
  Message=Could not find file 'C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\release\ACRONYM_DB.mdb'.
  Source=Microsoft Office Access Database Engine
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader()
       at AcronymFinder.Model.Database.AcronymDatabase.HistoricalDef(String acrName) in c:\Users\Mark\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\AcronymFinder\AcronymFinder\Model\Database\AcronymDatabase.cs:line 28
       at AcronymFinder.ViewModel.MainViewModel.set_SelectedAcronym(Acronym value) in c:\Users\Mark\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\AcronymFinder\AcronymFinder\ViewModel\MainViewModel.cs:line 315
  InnerException:
```

I know the error has got to be with the query I'm using but what is it I need to do differently?  Also I am using a 64 bit version of Access 2013.

Comment: What if you remove the `ACRONYM_DB.` from the name of the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not include the database name in the `SELECT` statement:

```
myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM ACRONYM WHERE ACRONYM_NAME=" + acrName;
```

That change should stop the db engine from complaining that it can't find *ACRONYM_DB.mdb*.

However the revised statement could still fail, with a different error, if your *ACRONYM_NAME* field is text datatype.  If it is text, you could avoid a missing parameter value complaint by including quotes before and after the value of *acrName*:

```
myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM ACRONYM WHERE ACRONYM_NAME='" + acrName + "'";
```

But, really, a parameter query would be a better approach because you would be protected against SQL injection and you wouldn't need to bother about quotes if *acrName* is a text value.

Comment: Yeah I'm definitely going to addParameter on this to parameterize it.  Just getting it working.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to quote your value:

```
    myCommand.CommandText = "[..snip..]ACRONYM_NAME='" + acrName + "'";
                                                    ^-----------^^^^^^^
```

without the quotes, you're doing

```
ACRONYM_NAME=foo
```

instead of

```
ACORNYM_NAME='foo'
```

which means the DB is looking for some unknown/non-existent **FIELD** named `foo`, instead of string `'foo'`.

Answer (score 0):

Add the Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library to your references.